# Laravel, how to delete all records but the first one of that day

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

So I have a table to log profile followers every 10 minutes to keep a record of the increase/decrease.

However after the current day I only need to keep the last record of that day. Is there a simple way in Laravel to delete all records a part from the last one recorded every day.

I've tried searching and searching but comes up with nothing and feel like I'm going to create something overly complicated to accomplish this.

Comment: You can get the last record of that date by a select query, and then delete all records of that date except the one you previusly get by a delete query. Or you can use a subquery too

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a query like this.

```sql
DELETE
FROM logs
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM logs
    WHERE created_at BETWEEN 2022-02-28 00:00:00 AND 2022-02-28 23:59:59
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
    OFFSET 1
)
```

Assuming you have a date variable, you could make the query like this using the [`whereDate` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses):

```php
$date = '2022-02-28'; // Y-m-d format. This is important.

DB::table('logs')
    ->whereIn('id', function ($sub) use ($date) {
        $sub->select('id')
            ->from('logs')
            ->whereDate('created_at', $date)
            ->orderByDesc('created_at')
            ->offset(1);
    })
    ->delete();
```